# Jupiter Notebook:Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64')

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to fit my data using my feature selection but whenever I try I get this error

```
Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').
```

Not sure if if there's a fix to this or if I can give it a different approach but what I am aware of is that if I am going to use a feature selection I have to apply it before my algorithm,

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

# In[1]:


from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split


# In[2]:


import pandas as pd


# In[3]:


import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# In[4]:


import numpy as np


# In[5]:


import seaborn as sns
import statsmodels.api as sm
import mglearn as mg
get_ipython().run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'inline')


# In[6]:


from sklearn.ensemble import AdaBoostRegressor
from sklearn.feature_selection import RFE
from sklearn. feature_selection import SelectFromModel


# In[7]:


first_file = pd.read_csv(r"/Users/feliperivas/Downloads/MachineLearningCVE/Friday-WorkingHours-Afternoon-DDos.pcap_ISCX.csv")


# In[8]:


print(first_file)


# In[9]:


second_file = pd.read_csv(r"/Users/feliperivas/Downloads/MachineLearningCVE/Friday-WorkingHours-Afternoon-PortScan.pcap_ISCX.csv")
third_file = pd.read_csv(r"/Users/feliperivas/Downloads/MachineLearningCVE/Friday-WorkingHours-Morning.pcap_ISCX.csv")
fourth_file = pd.read_csv(r"/Users/feliperivas/Downloads/MachineLearningCVE/Monday-WorkingHours.pcap_ISCX.csv")
fifth_file = pd.read_csv(r"/Users/feliperivas/Downloads/MachineLearningCVE/Thursday-WorkingHours-Afternoon-Infilteration.pcap_ISCX.csv")
sixth_file = pd.read_csv(r"/Users/feliperivas/Downloads/MachineLearningCVE/Thursday-WorkingHours-Morning-WebAttacks.pcap_ISCX.csv")
seventh_file = pd.read_csv(r"/Users/feliperivas/Downloads/MachineLearningCVE/Tuesday-WorkingHours.pcap_ISCX.csv")
eighth_file = pd.read_csv(r"/Users/feliperivas/Downloads/MachineLearningCVE/Wednesday-workingHours.pcap_ISCX.csv")


# In[10]:


print(second_file)


# In[11]:


print(third_file)


# In[12]:


print(fourth_file)


# In[13]:


print(fifth_file)


# In[14]:


print(sixth_file)


# In[15]:


print(seventh_file)


# In[16]:


print(eighth_file)


# In[17]:


first_file = first_file.loc[:,~first_file.columns.duplicated()]


# In[18]:


print(first_file)


# In[19]:


df_list = [first_file, second_file,third_file,fourth_file, fifth_file, sixth_file, seventh_file,eighth_file]


# In[20]:


merged_data = pd.concat(df_list)


# In[21]:


print(merged_data)


# print(merged_data.shape)

# In[22]:


print(merged_data.shape)


# In[23]:


print(first_file.shape)


# In[24]:


print(second_file.shape)


# In[25]:


print(third_file.shape)


# In[26]:


print(fourth_file.shape)


# In[27]:


print(fifth_file.shape)
        

# In[28]:


print(sixth_file.shape)


# In[29]:


print(seventh_file.shape)


# In[30]:


print(eighth_file.shape)


# In[31]:


# 2830540 number weretrying to get


# In[32]:


# df = merged_data.dropna()


# In[33]:


print(merged_data.shape)


# In[34]:


merged_data.dropna(inplace = True)


# In[35]:


print(merged_data.shape)


# In[36]:


df = merged_data 


# In[37]:


df.shape


# In[38]:


df.dropna(inplace = True)


# In[39]:


keys_num = len(df.keys())


# In[40]:


df.keys()


# In[41]:


df.head()


# In[42]:


df.keys()


# In[43]:


y= df[' Label']


# In[44]:


y


# In[45]:


X = df.drop(' Label',axis=1)


# In[46]:


X


# In[47]:


estimator = AdaBoostRegressor(n_estimators=100, random_state=0)


# In[48]:


selector = RFE(estimator, n_features_to_select=12, step=1)


# In[49]:


selector.fit(X, y)


# In[50]:


cid = AdaBoostRegressor( n_estimators=100,random_state=0)


# In[51]:


X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.2)


# In[52]:


cid.fit(X_train, y_train)


# In[ ]:


trainning_score = cid.score(X_train, y_train)


# In[ ]:


print("Training Score: {0}".format(trainning_score))


# In[ ]:


testing_score = cid.score(X_test, y_test)


# In[ ]:


print("Test Score: {0}".format(testing_score))


# In[ ]:


print(X_train.shape)


# In[ ]:


print(X_test.shape)


# In[ ]:


estimator = AdaBoostRegressor(n_estimators=100, random_state=0)


# In[ ]:


selector = RFE(estimator, n_features_to_select=5, step=1)


# In[ ]:


selector = selector.fit(X_train, y_train)


# In[ ]:


trainning_score = selector.score(X_train, y_train)


# In[ ]:


print("Training Score: {0}".format(trainning_score))


# In[ ]:
```

> This is the ERROR!!!:

> In[ ]:   selector.fit(X, y)
>
> > --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
> > last)  in 
> > ----> 1 selector.fit(X, y)
>
> ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/feature_selection/_rfe.py
> in fit(self, X, y)
> 182             The target values.
> 183         """
> --> 184         return self._fit(X, y)
> 185
> 186     def _fit(self, X, y, step_score=None):
>
> ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/feature_selection/_rfe.py
> in _fit(self, X, y, step_score)
> 191
> 192         tags = self._get_tags()
> --> 193         X, y = self._validate_data(
> 194             X, y, accept_sparse="csc",
> 195             ensure_min_features=2,
>
> ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/base.py in
> _validate_data(self, X, y, reset, validate_separately, **check_params)
> 431                 y = check_array(y, **check_y_params)
> 432             else:
> --> 433                 X, y = check_X_y(X, y, **check_params)
> 434             out = X, y
> 435
>
> ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py
> in inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
> 61             extra_args = len(args) - len(all_args)
> 62             if extra_args <= 0:
> ---> 63                 return f(*args, **kwargs)
> 64
> 65             # extra_args > 0
>
> ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py
> in check_X_y(X, y, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order,
> copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, multi_output,
> ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, y_numeric, estimator)
> 812         raise ValueError("y cannot be None")
> 813
> --> 814     X = check_array(X, accept_sparse=accept_sparse,
> 815                     accept_large_sparse=accept_large_sparse,
> 816                     dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy,
>
> ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py
> in inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
> 61             extra_args = len(args) - len(all_args)
> 62             if extra_args <= 0:
> ---> 63                 return f(*args, **kwargs)
> 64
> 65             # extra_args > 0
>
> ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py
> in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype,
> order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd,
> ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, estimator)
> 661
> 662         if force_all_finite:
> --> 663             _assert_all_finite(array,
> 664                                allow_nan=force_all_finite == 'allow-nan')
> 665
>
> ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py
> in _assert_all_finite(X, allow_nan, msg_dtype)
> 101                 not allow_nan and not np.isfinite(X).all()):
> 102             type_err = 'infinity' if allow_nan else 'NaN, infinity'
> --> 103             raise ValueError(
> 104                     msg_err.format
> 105                     (type_err,ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').

Comment: please post your entire erro5r message beginning with traceback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem by replacing the infinite data with nan and then dropping nan data

```
xy = X
xy[" Label"] = y_df
#xy = dataframe
# Replace infinite updated data with nan
X.replace([np.inf,-np. inf], np.nan, inplace=True)
# Drop rows with NaN
X. dropna (inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the answer you want to hear, but it has some validity.

A good practice when trying to do almost any type of training or data analysis is to first clean the data. One of those steps can include removing or treating 'Nan', 'infinity', or otherwise out-of-place outliers.

There is a multitude of ways to do this, but for your case, I would suggest doing all of these to start with:

1. Remove rows with Nan values.
2. Remove rows with infinity values.
3. Move all values so that they are within the float64 data size, or remove rows that contain numbers outside of the float64 data size.
4. Remove columns that have an excessively large range.

Here is a function I use often to first inspect data for cleaning.

```
def calc_summary_for(feature_name:str, data:DataFrame) -> DataFrame:
"""
Calculates Summary Features in list of 'summary_feature_names'.

Parameters
----------
feature_name : str
    Name of feature for summary to be calculated for. required
data : pandas.DataFrame object
    A DataFrame object containg column named feature_name. required

Returns : DataFrame object of summary calculated features. 
"""
summary_feature_names = ['Feature Name', 'Cardinality', 'Non-null Count', 'Null Count', 'Min', '25th', 'Mean', 
                         '50th', '75th', 'Max', 'Std. Dev','Outlier Count Low', 'Outlier Count High']

# Create DataFrame to return and list at loc to DataFram
frame2return = pd.DataFrame(columns=summary_feature_names)
list2add = []

# Find claculated features that have bult in functions
list2add.append(feature_name)
list2add.append(data.shape[0])
list2add.append(data[feature_name].notnull().sum())
list2add.append(data[feature_name].isnull().sum())
list2add.append(data[feature_name].min())
list2add.append(data[feature_name].quantile(q=0.25))
list2add.append(data[feature_name].mean())

# Save for Calcuating IQR
list2add.append(data[feature_name].quantile(q=0.5))
Q1 = data[feature_name].quantile(q=0.5)
list2add.append(data[feature_name].quantile(q=0.75))
Q3 = data[feature_name].quantile(q=0.75)

list2add.append(data[feature_name].max())
list2add.append(data[feature_name].std())
# Find IQR
IQR = Q3 - Q1

# Find Range for outliers
outerBoundLow = Q1 - (1.5 * IQR)
outerBoundHigh = Q3 + (1.5 * IQR)


# Find calculated features using IQR counting outliers
countLow = 0
countHigh = 0
countInBounds = 0
for i in data[feature_name]:
    if i < outerBoundLow:
        countLow +=1
    elif i > outerBoundHigh:
        countHigh +=1
    else :
        countInBounds +=1

list2add.append(countLow)
list2add.append(countHigh)

# Add list to Dataframe and return it
frame2return.loc[len(frame2return)] = list2add
return frame2return
```